# Case sensitivity in Git

Tags: git, case-sensitive

I've run into a problem with git. Basically I set to false `core.ignorecase` because I wanted to change the case of the names of some folders (since I'm under OSX with a case-insensitive filesystem, the changes weren't shown otherwise). When I pulled my data, I've noticed that now every renamed folder appears twice on the repository, with both the old and the new name. I don't know what to do to remove the old folders since they don't appear locally (I've try to set `core.ignorecase` to true again but it isn't helping).

Comment: Maybe you could create a ext3 filesystem over a image, mount it, and pull in this case-sensitive filesystem.

Comment: @AndréPuel well, actually I was looking for something ‘easier’. :P but thanks for the advice, I'll go for it if I don't find other solutions.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

May be a workaround similar to [this comment in an msysgit issue](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=286#c10) (for another case-insensitive OS: Windows) could help?

> I've encountered this same issue.  Refactored a package name in Eclipse and switching to a previous build broke due to the folder name not reverting.  I'm using Windows 7, Git 1.7.0.2.msysgit.0
>
> My folder was renamed in Windows to "`folder`" but was displayed as "`Folder`" in Git.
> I fixed the issue by renaming it to "`Folder`" in Windows and then running:

```
git mv "Folder" "Folder2"
git mv "Folder2" "folder"
```

---

Note that **since git 2.0.1 (June 2014), `git mv Folder folder` should just work!**

See "[Git: Changing capitalization of filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979063/6309)"

Comment: I noticed that when renaming in this way, the second rename can take a *looooong* time. The answer is to be patient; the folder will eventually rename, then you can commit it.

Comment: Another way to get the same is renaming "Folder" to "Folder2" and make a commit and then "Folder2" to "folder" and amend the last commit.

Comment: @DaniCE I have just edited the answer: with git 2.0.1 this should be much simpler.

Answer (score 62):

Use the following command on macOS. This will change your git configuration to be case sensitive on filenames.

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

You can set this globally by editing `~/.gitconfig` and setting it under `core` such as:

```
[core]
    ignoreCase = false
```

Comment: I did exactly the opposite in order to make git succeed doing a rebase that included a case rename. Thanks!

Comment: This option is not to tell git to be case-sensitive, instead it is to make git compatible with the filesystem if is misconfigured.

Answer (score 24):

You can create a disk image (preferably a sparsebundle disk image) with a case-sensitive file system and checkout your git repository there.

The Disk Utility screenshot below shows how to create a case-sensitive disk image.

[image: Disk Utility Settings]

Comment: A much better, permanent, solution to this problem and other mysteries resulting from case sensitivity. I made the disk image; copied my old Git repos into it; made a symbolic link from where I used to keep all my git repos to the new, sparse bundle version. Back to normal workflow never to encounter this again.

Comment: The disk created in this way is very very slow.

Comment: @MinqiPan, I had the same concern, but it shouldn't be if you create an APFS volume. [APFS volumes can exist in the same "container" partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System#Space_sharing), thus having no performance penalty.

Answer (score 13):

Mac OS X by default is "case insensitive but case preserving". This is an important distinction.

I suggest you create another disk image, and specifically format it as "HFS Case Sensitive".

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but the post above this solved everything!

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of bad software (Adobe, of course) relies on the default broken OSX filesystem. Be wary.

Answer (score 7):

```
git mv "Folder" "Folder2"
git mv "Folder2" "folder"
git commit -a -m "my message"
```

Comment: Yup. You have to go ahead and commit it too. ++

Answer (score 2):

There is a longish recent thread on case sensitivity issues on the git@vger.kernel.org discussion forum titled [Bug? Git checkout fails with a wrong error message](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/188469) which highlights the issues, and things to try, of case sensitivity between different platforms.