# GitHub shows directories twice that have been renamed

Tags: git, github, repository

I have a git [repository](https://github.com/luukvisser/OSCAAR) that had a directory called `Code`. We wanted to remove the capitalization and change the directory name to `code`. We made that change locally and pushed it to the repo. Now on GitHub, it appears that the repository has two copies of the directory, one with each capitalization. When you clone the repo, you get the directory labeled `code` on GitHub, but the local repository calls it `Code`, and there is no `Code` directory in the local repo.

Any ideas on how to remove the capitalized `Code` from GitHub?

Comment: Found [this potential solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904327/case-sensitivity-in-git) after I posted the question, giving it a shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the github page of your project, it seems you solved your problem.

I bet you moved your folders using `mv` and `git add`-ed the uppercase-version and did not stage the removal of the lowercase-version.  You have to "add" the deletion.

To move things around, **`git mv`** takes care of everything for you.

Comment: Yup! Thanks for the recap.