# Updating file names in Git from camel case to all lower case

Tags: git

I had some files in my git named like this:  `"myCamelFile.rb"`
I just right clicked on my IDE and renamed them to all lower case so like `"mycamelfile.rb"`
But when I do a `git statu`s I don't get any message that these are changed.

What should be done now?

Comment: What operating system are you using? I'm not sure, but it might be an issue with case-insensitive file systems.

Comment: HFS is case-insensitive per default. Try, `git mv`

Comment: @nif oh shoot! Ok now what should I do? :)

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904327/case-sensitivity-in-git

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Step one:** Rename them to some temp names such as `"mycamelfile_temp.rb"` 
**Step two:** Rename them back to `"mycamelfile.rb"`  now all in lower case.

Comment: @EricFromSouthPark Step 3: Profit!

Comment: Ok that works, but you should have said that after first renaming (Step one), we should **commit**, and then rename again (step two).

Comment: This answer makes git commit very messy when renaming multiple files. I would recommend the other answer by Someone instead. changing git config with "git config core.ignorecase false"

Answer (score 15):

You can just change this git config as follows:

`git config core.ignorecase false`

Answer (score 10):

You can use this to rename a file in git. You will then need to stage and commit that change.

```
git mv application/view/old_file_name.php application/view/new_file_name.php
```

Here are the complete docs on the mv command:
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mv.html

Comment: ok but now if I browse to my folder on file system, I am seeing the all lower case file names...I just renamed them the normal way we rename any file....so still I can refer to their old name too? In order to use this command.

Comment: Unfortunately running `git mv` only once in a case insensitive environment will not cut it. You will need to do it in two steps. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011625/git-mv-and-only-change-case-of-directory

Answer (score 4):

to rename a file or folder needs below step:

> first step is change git config on project & global:
>
> ```
> git config core.ignorecase false
> git config --global core.ignorecase false
> ```
>
> then rename file or folder:
>
> ```
> git mv -f myCamelFile.rb mycamelFile.rb
> ```

Answer (score 3):

An additional tip which is not mentioned in the accepted answer:

> Step one: Rename them to some temp names such as "mycamelfile_temp.rb" Step two: Rename them back to "mycamelfile.rb" now all in lower case.

After the first renaming (Step one), we should **COMMIT**, and then rename again (step two).