# Unable to discard all local files in git

Tags: git

I have 2 files that are in my working directory. I want to completely discard these files so I can switch branches.

There are many helpful guides online, and I have tried every answer I can find to remove these files, yet they still persist.

```
user@machine:~/Code/foo$ git status
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   src/test/foo.c
    modified:   src/test/bar.c
```

Commands I have tried based on other stackoverflow questions.

```
 git reset 

 git reset --hard HEAD^

 git stash save --keep-index
 git stash drop

 git checkout HEAD -- $(git ls-files -m)

 git clean -f
 git clean -dfx

 git checkout -- .

 git checkout -- *

 git checkout 123456

 git reset --hard 123456

 git reset HEAD --hard
```

Amazingly, after every command, I find the files are still present!

```
user@machine:~/Code/foo$ git status
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   src/test/foo.c
    modified:   src/test/bar.c
```

Since there are only 2 files, I know I *could* just recheck them out one by one. However if this happened again and I had 100 files, I want to know the procedure to blow all of them away in one sweep.

```
 git checkout src/test/foo.c
 git checkout src/test/bar.c
```

**Update**

Aparently not even a git checkout works

```
git checkout src/test/foo.c
echo $?
0
git checkout src/test/bar.c
echo $?
0

user@machine:~/Code/foo$ git status
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   src/test/foo.c
    modified:   src/test/bar.c
```

These files just wont go away.

**Update2**

I've tried these command as well with no luck.

```
git reflog
git checkout HEAD@{17}

git init
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

**Update3**

Stashing does nothing.

```
git checkout master
git stash
git stash pop
git stash drop
```

Deleting the files does not work either.

```
user@machine:~/Code/foo$ git rm --cached $(git ls-files -m)
rm 'src/test/foo.c'
rm 'src/test/bar.c'

user@machine:~/Code/foo$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 162 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
(use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:   src/test/foo.c
    deleted:   src/test/bar.c
```

Comment: `git checkout -f yourCurrentBranch`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I clear my local working directory in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673407/how-do-i-clear-my-local-working-directory-in-git)

Comment: Yes, I saw that question, and I've tried every answer I could find in it. No luck

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I revert all local changes in a GIT managed project to previous state?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146973/how-do-i-revert-all-local-changes-in-a-git-managed-project-to-previous-state)

Comment: Yes, I've read that question too, and I've tried all the answers suggested there with no luck.

Comment: It almost sounds like some other application that's running has those files open and resaves them to disk when a change in the file is detected. I know it's kind of extreme, but have you tried closing all applications and doing a full shutdown and restart of your computer?

Comment: Good idea @GregBurghardt I'll try a restart.

Comment: @GregBurghardt restarted, yet the issue continues. This is mildly infuriating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

In git diff, it showed that the file name was lowercase `foo.bar`, however when I actually inspected the file it was `Foo.bar`.

I am on a mac which has a case insensitive file system.

I should be able to fix it by manually moving the files

[Case sensitivity in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904327/case-sensitivity-in-git)

Answer (score 1):

For all unstaged files use (note the period at the end). This works for me (as of git v 1.8.4.5)

```
git checkout -- .
```

**alternatively** you can put everything in stash;

```
git stash
```

that way you can still come back to the way you were, or you can even apply those changes on another branch:

```
git stash pop (this command applies the latest stash)
```

or if you don't need the changes anymore:

```
git stash drop
```

Comment: I have tried all 4 of these suggestion and yet the files are still present

Comment: it looks like something strange is happening... on what branch are you? perform a "git branch -a"... maybe you are in "detached head" state?

Comment: Chris Maes awswer is the best option ,  stashing them will solve your problem.

Comment: I am on the master branch, @KSNidhin I have tried git stash with no luck

Comment: if you perform git diff, what is your output?

Comment: git diff looks as expected ( 400 lines of tests written by someone, not me)

Comment: where did you get this git repository? How did the changes come there? Did you do anything special? this is all very strange!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very much like line-ending troubles, you've told git to do automatic conversions on checkin and the result of those conversions won't match the committed state.  Check `.git/info/attributes` and `.gitattributes` for `text` attributes:

> `text`
>
> `This attribute enables and controls end-of-line normalization.`**`When a text file is normalized, its line endings are converted to LF in the repository.`**

If someone has checked in files containing CRLFs, I understand `text=auto` is a good way to, erm, find them.

Comment: Good to know, it looks like I don't have an attributes file in the info directory.