# Problems with the React components directory on Github

Tags: reactjs, git, github

So, I started a react project with the components directory named 'Components'

It was then renamed 'components' a few days later ...

Recently I have noticed on github that there are 2 directories, Components and components, both show active commits and seem to share the files between them.

On my text editor I can only see a components folder, on my mac finder I can only see a components folder ... I cant see a hidden file called Components ...

But its causing me issues when i rebase and it clearly exists, can anyone help ?

Comment: The macOS file system is case-insensitive IIRC - perhaps the answers to this question may help: [Case sensitivity in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8904327/996081)

Comment: Consider making yourself a case-sensitive volume on the Mac, so that you can work with all those darned Linux folks. :-) See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59516454/1256452).